# How to frame multiple lines with a box and not alter text width

Tags: typography, framed, box

Please have a look at this mininal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}

\title{Box}
\author{LR}
\date{September 2020}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\begin{framed}
\blindtext
\end{framed}
%\medskip\noindent
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{1mm}
\fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
        \blindtext
        }%
    }%
%\medskip
\end{document}
```

As you can [image: see] see both tries resulted in the space available for the text being somewhat compressed. I would like instead the box to have a larger width such that the text retains its original breaking line points, is it possible?

Comment: I believe the mdframed package specializes in placing frames outside the text area.  Or you can increase the effective width of the text area using (negative) \leftskip and \rightskip.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, based on `tcolorbox` library.  I don't know how to use a larger default frame; consequently, I hide it and create a new one with `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{Bbox}{%
  \tcolorbox[%
  empty,
  parbox=false,
  noparskip,
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  frame hidden, % default frame hidden
  boxrule=0pt, % default frame hidden
  colback=white,
  left=-4pt, right=-4pt,
  before skip=4ex plus 2pt,
  after skip=3.5ex plus 2pt,
  overlay unbroken and last={% new frame
    \draw[color=blue, line width=1.25pt]
    ($(frame.north west)+(-1em, .5ex)$)
    rectangle ($(frame.south east)+(1em, -.5ex)$);
  }]
}{\endtcolorbox}


\title{Using tcolorbox package}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Bbox}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{Bbox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```